# Image boundary detection opencv python for camera feed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on my project based on image processing in opencv using python.

I have a page with a blue rectangular border inside which is captured by camera.I need to detect the boundary to extract contents inside the boundary for further processing.I have tried with contours ,bounding Rect and also , Hough circles by drawing 4 circles at the corners of rectangle.

I used hsv conversion for detection of blue.

I'm failing to get the boundary exactly. Here is my code.
`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

img=np.zeros((640,480,3),np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

cv2.createTrackbar('kernel','image',1,10,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('iteration','image',1,10,nothing)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(5,5),0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    ker     = cv2.getTrackbarPos('kernel','image')
    its     = cv2.getTrackbarPos('iteration','image')

    lower_array=np.array([75,100,100])
    upper_array=np.array([110,255,255])

### Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_array, upper_array)
    edges = cv2.Canny(mask,90,200)

## Image Processing to obtain better image    
    kernel = np.ones((ker,ker),np.uint8)

    erosion = cv2.erode(edges,kernel,iterations = its)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = its)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

##    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(closing,127,255,0)
    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closing,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    contours_poly=[]
    bounding_rect=[]
    hull=[]

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= closing)

##  Find the largest contour
    max_area = 0
    if(contours):
        for cnt in contours:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if area > max_area:
                    max_area = area
                    best_cnt = cnt

    ## Finding centroids of best_cnt and draw a circle there
        M = cv2.moments(best_cnt)
        cx,cy = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),5,(0,255,0),-1)

    ##To approximate the contour
        epsilon = 0.01*cv2.arcLength(best_cnt,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(best_cnt,epsilon,True)


    ## Draw the largest contour
    cv2.drawContours(res, [best_cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)

        #x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(best_cnt)
        #cv2.rectangle(res,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('image1',frame)
    cv2.imshow('image2',mask)
    cv2.imshow('image3',dilation)
    cv2.imshow('image6',edges)
    cv2.imshow('image4',closing)
    cv2.imshow('image5',res)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
`
```

Comment: Show us the sample images on which you are working ?

Comment: Sorry,being a new user i m not able to upload my image.It is a blue rectangle inside which i have 9 orange squares.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6C5N9IxBo0HUGdXeV9mV1FCSkU&authuser=0            I hope u find the image

Comment: Maybe its a problem with your hsv values. Try [110,100,100] and [130,255,255]

Comment: @Specas The blue colour i m using is lighter shade which gives better result with 75-110.I have tried your suggestion too.But the problem still persists